# Is this an alias for a table in Oracle SQL?

Tags: oracle

I'm new to Oracle SQL and trying to figure out the syntax. I have some code like this:

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE(
  ssn NUMBER,
  id NUMBER,
  PRIMARY KEY(ssn, id)
);

SELECT e.ssn, e.id
FROM EMPLOYEE e
....
```

In the line "FROM EMPLOYEE e" what does the e refer to? Is it an alias for table EMPLOYEE?

Answer (score 0):

Yes...... for convinience you are again renaming the table

Comment: No "kind of" about it.  It's an alias.

Answer (score 0):

Yes giving [ALIAS](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/alias.php)
 makes your query more readable and simple.